# Lazy Loading In GORM Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am trying to get lazy loading in `Java Clas`s of relationship in `groovy domain class`, when i use `lazy: false` it works but when i mark `lazy:true` then it did not get table data.
I am using below code :-

**Domain Class :-**

Product Domain Class :-

```
class Products {

    static mapping = {
        version  false
        id name: 'productId', generator:'assigned'
        }

    String productId
    String reference 
    String code  
    String codetype 
}
```

Stock Domain Class :-

```
class Stock {

    static mapping = {
        version  false
        id name: 'stockId', generator:'assigned'
        product column:"product",lazy:true
        }

    String stockId

    Products product


    static belongsTo = [product: Products] 
}
```

**Services Class :-**

```
@Transactional
class StockService {
    public List<Stock> getStockList() {


            def stock = Stock.list()
             return stock

        }
}
```

**Java Class to get Stock data and Product Data :-**

```
   StockService stockService = Grails.get(StocktService.class);
   List<Stock> stock = stockService.getStockList();
   Products product = stock.get(0).getProduct();
```

But the product object is showing `null`. it should should product data. is there anything wrong with above code?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses proxy object to enable lazy loading. A proxy object is an object of runtime created subclass of our domain/model class i.e Products and Stock in this case.

Now on calling stock.getProduct() it will invoke the method from the subclass. Here it will first hit a query to the database and then call the code from our method.

Important point for lazy loading to work is that hibernate session should be open.

Grails service method is by default transactional and there is session but when it comes to the java class it seems that there is no session.

Trying opening a session in java class and in the same call your grails service method. And before closing the session try getting the product object from stock.

Comment: How to open `Grails` `hibernate` session in `Java` class ?